# What do you do if you get bothersome local calls to an international number?

Tags: international, fcc, jurisdiction, donotcall

I've come to an issue that FCC.gov's [DoNotCall.gov](http://donotcall.gov) list does not accept Canadian area codes.

However, I kept getting unwanted calls from several American companies trying to scam me with their extended warranty for my US car, possibly not getting the memo that they're calling my Canadian number instead, even though I'm actually physically located in the US as they somehow did nonetheless expect.

I've repeatedly asked them to take me off their lists, and asked them where did they get the number from in the first place, and I also finally did add my number to [DNCL.GC.Ca](https://www.lnnte-dncl.gc.ca/) and it finally stopped somewhere thereafter, but I'm not too sure why.

Is there an exchange of the information between DoNotCall and DNCL?

Does each company has to respect both at the same time, if they don't have an area code filter in the first place?

Would I have to be filing complaints of DNCL violation with the Canadian authorities for my Canadian number, even though both me and the offender are located in the US, including at the time of call?

Comment: There are lots of exemptions to the DNC list.  One of them is a preexisting business relationship.  Also never say "Take me off your list"  The wording you want to use is "Put me on your Do not call list"

Comment: @Chad, When a bunch of random extended warranty scammers call you about the car you bought brand new, years earlier from an official dealer, and you have no idea where they bought your number from, and they don't tell you, either, that's clearly not a pre-existing business relationship at all.

Comment: BTW, I'm also interested if I could possibly sue them -- they've been calling me several times a day for many days last year, even after I repeatedly told them to stop.  It has supposedly been multiple different extended warranty scammers that have been doing it at the same time or in turns.

Comment: They get your number through some of the incentives that you are "given" when you purchase that new car.  There was one of the forms that authorized the dealer to share your information with their business partners in order to offer you that deal.  The how can you sue them part is probably on topic though.

Comment: @Chad, I got this car brand new years ago, and the VW dealer I got it from didn't have this specific phone number they've been calling, so, it either got to them from a Canadian dealer that I've merely gotten some service from, from VW Credit, or, I guess, could have been from some kind of combination of various records and restrictions for the other numbers.

Comment: The dealer pays a franchise fee to VW And agrees to meet their standards when selling the vehicles but there is no obligation to restrict their offers to VW provided services.  As a result much of the package of warranty and other "new car benefits" that you receive is actually a 3rd party package.